# Not receiving when posting a message through bot using an outgoing webhook on teams

Tags: node.js, microsoft-teams, ngrok

I'm running a node.js server as my local using the method specified [here](https://github.com/officeDev/msteams-samples-outgoing-webhook-nodejs). Although, I'm unable to receive anything at the ngrok server itself when I @mention my bot and send the message. I've followed all the steps as provided in the link diligently. Is there any way I could debug this?

Comment: Your link is wrong btw (http://officedev/msteams-samples-outgoing-webhook-nodejs - it should be https://github.com/OfficeDev/msteams-samples-outgoing-webhook-nodejs.

Comment: But aside from that, what is the URL you are sending to in the outgoing webhook in Teams?

Comment: I'm adding the https link that I get from ngrok. The problem is that the bot isnt posting to ngrok itself

Comment: Confirming you have copy/pasted your ngrok endpoint into the "Callback URL" as described [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/concepts/outgoingwebhook). Can you post to your ngrok URL using Postman/Curl?